# Is it possible to retrieve high score from leaderboards without user sign-in in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I want to show user's high score of the game. But I have problem that some users not login to game center. Can I retrieve only high score from gamecenter with out user login in iOS?

Comment: And how would that work? You want to ask the server for a specific user's high score, but  you don't want to log in to the server. I'm thinking nope.

Comment: No I want top score from over all users. Just highest score no extra details. with out user login.

Comment: You want to ask the server for the overall high score, but don't want to log in to the server. How would that work, exactly?

Comment: Actually I have a  game, And I implemented leader board. Now a user played my game but not logged in to game center. I want to show him that you are near to high score on store. Please log in to submit your score and compete. I just want to get high score from leader board, is it possible?

Comment: No, I can't see how it would be possible. You have to be logged in to Game Center to get stats like leaderboards.